# Compare urls in Django Template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

In a django template I don't want to show some element in case if the url/path is a specific one. In pseudo:

```
 {% if not url = account:detail %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give your urls a name ( url_name ) in urls.py file and then you can compare directly using [HttpRequest.resolver_match](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.resolver_match) object available in template.

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('articles/<int:year>/', views.year_archive, name='news_year_archive'),
    # ...
]
```

In template you compare it like,

```
{% if request.resolver_match.url_name == "news_year_archive" %}
   ...your stuff
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3):

We can do this in two steps here:

1. first we resulve the url, and assign it to a variable (here `url2`); and
2. next compare the urls

So:

```
{% url account:detail as url2 %}
{% if url != url2 %}
    <!-- ... (do something) ... -->
{% endif %}
```

Note however that if two urls are syntactically different (for example `yourdomain.com/foo` and `/foo`), that they *per se* point to something different.

If you want access to the *current* path, you can - like @RajaSimon says, usually use `request.path` (given you render the template with a `RequestContext`, `render(..)`, or another way to pass the `request` object).

Comment: @user3541631: your comment is quite confusing, can you please reread it, and fix the "grammar"?

Comment: @user3541631 You can get the current page url using `request.path` is that what you're asking? If so you're condition should be `{% if request.path != account_detail_url %}`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - I want to check if the current url/page is the same with a predefined page. The current page/url I can get from request.path. To compare request.path with 'account:detail' I think I need 'resolve', no?  But how I set resolve in template ?

Comment: @user3541631: but you resolve it in the template, here we resolve it, and the path is stored in the `url2` variable. So you can compare `{% if request.url != url2 %}`.

Comment: @user3541631 In template you can use `url` template builtin to resolve [url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url).